# Whether it is necessary for a strictly increasing function that is continuous to be bijective?

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I would like to have this clarrified. Because as per the definition of strictly increasing  function it is clear that f'(x) exists. so if f' exists then clearly f is continuous. why is that it must be bijective?

Is there any example to show that I am wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It will be injective, regardless of continuity.  If $x \neq y$, say $x < y$, then $f(x) < f(y)$, and in particular $f(x) != f(y)$.  It may or may not be surjective depending on the definition of the codomain.

Comment: Also, it is not clear that $f'(x)$ exists - in fact, it need not be differentiable.

Comment: First of all, a strictly increasing function does not need to be differentiable or even continuous, e.g. $f(x):=(x+2 )\chi_{(-\infty,1)}+(x+3)\chi_{[1,+\infty)}$. Moreover, if $f'$ exists, $f$ does not have to be surjective, as $f=\arctan$ shows

Comment: So a function like $f(x)=e^x$?

Comment: Take $f(x) = {1 \over \pi}\arctan x$. If you take it as $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ it is not bijective, but as  $f: \mathbb{R} \to (-1,1)$ it is.

Comment: Thank you . I was in the wrong impression that a strictly increasing function is always differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

What about $x\mapsto x + \chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$? It is strictly increasing but discontinuous at $x=0$.